# How to set gnome-session-flashback as default in 16.04?

Tags: unity, login, gnome-flashback

I customized my system by installing Ubuntu 16.04 and replacing Unity with gnome-session-flashback.

How can I switch Unity desktop to GNOME desktop without selecting the session at the login screen?

Comment: Select it once, and it becomes the default session, until another is selected.

Comment: thanks for reply, but i need to set from display manager or anything else like boot up.